# Combining Random Variables to get the Variance

Tags: probability, statistics

So $$\operatorname{Var}(aX + bY) = a^2 \operatorname{Var}(X) + b^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y).$$

But I have also seen:  $$\operatorname{Var}(aX - bY) = a \operatorname{Var}(X) + b \operatorname{Var}(Y).$$

I don't know when I should use either of them. When do I use the one when you square the '$a$' and '$b$' and when do I not?

Comment: The first one is correct (if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, that is).

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $Var(X)=E[(X-EX)^2]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.

To compute the variance of two random variables you would evaluate: 
$$E[(X+Y)^2]-E[X+Y]^2=E[X^2+2XY+Y^2]-(E[X]+E[Y])^2$$$$=E[X^2]+2E[XY]+E[Y^2]-E[X]^2-2E[X]E[Y]-E[Y]^2=Var(X)+Var(Y)+2(E[XY]-E[X]E[Y])$$Hence we see that if the last term is zero we obtain $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$. This happens when the covariance is zero (a condition which is met when the random variables are independent).

Try to do the same computation now with scalars $a,b$ in front of your RV's to see what you get.